# Is "commit" statement in SQL itself a transaction?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, relational-database, commit

In SQL, every statement is a transaction.

If commit statement occurs inside a transaction block, and successfully executed then will there still be a chance that database state might get lost, if system crash immediately after this execution?

Answer (score 0):

> if system crash immediately after this execution

No I believe since the `COMMIT` has already been executed but yes while the `COMMIT` is still under progress. But a system failure of such may result in in-consistent state

Comment: So, if COMMIT is still under progress and system crashes, how the database will be in an inconsistent state, since actual transaction hasn't been completed. That means, database will rollback to the previous stable state. Am I right?

Comment: @AdityaNarkar, No since the underlying server already dead, the rollback operation will never happen

Comment: since the commit never happened, the database never changed its state.

Answer (score 0):

No, in SQL **every statement is NOT a transaction**. A transaction encompass a set of statements that are executed all as a group, or none at all, in order to keep data consistency.

Once the transaction is committed, a system crash will NOT undo the changes, unless there's a catastrophic unrecoverable error (most unlikely).

Some databases offer extra SQL statements to support the basic ones (as DDL, DML, etc.) for extra purposes. For example:

```
begin transaction;
savepoint;
commit;
rollback;
```

This depends on each database and these are NOT transactions. Just extra commands that take the form of a SQL statement (if your database defines them). The ones mentioned before are actually "transaction delimiters", and they do NOT form part of a transaction.

Comment: I guess this also depends on the *concrete* RDBMS - but in SQL Server for instance, if you *do not* specify your own (explicit) transaction, then any statement (including `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` , `DELETE`) **are** in fact executing inside their own (implicit) transaction - so in SQL Server you *could say* that each statement is in its own (implicit) transaction (unless you define your own, explicit one)

Comment: I'm no expert on SQL Server but it seems to me that when no transaction delimiters are set, it works in auto-commit mode. Some clients may set auto-commit on or off by default (that depends on the client). This means each SQL statement is implicitly enclosed in a "transaction begin" and "commit". Even if it looks like one, this doesn't make each SQL statement a transaction -- there's an important difference there.

Answer (score 0):

Commit/rollback signifies the end of a transaction. After it is executed, data is reflected across all other sessions, if its a commit.
If you feel commit itself as a transaction, you will need something else to finish that transaction, like rollback, or another commit. It will then be an endless loop.

Transaction is like a journey, commit/rollback are your destinations, not a good example but might help in understanding.

Comment: But what happens when system crashes while executing the COMMIT.

That means, system is executing the huge commit and suddenly it crashes. What will happen?

Comment: Well if you have db server outage while the commit was in progress, all others will also be gone. When you will try to restart it, thats when your *redo logs* and *archived redo logs* comes into picture. These are logs which are referred whenever commit or rollback is performed. They are associated with your instances and keep the track of your changes. They are also referred when your server is getting crashed and a recovery option is being tried. Archived redo logs are the offline storage for your redo logs.